# Group array of hashes on key and append nested array on another hash key

Tags: ruby

I need to reduce an array of hashes into a single hash if that hash key matches.

`my_array` is an array of hashes, each of which has two keys: one an active record object, the other an array of different active record objects, similar to:

```
my_array = [
  {
    first_hash_key: {id: 1, title: "my title"},
    second_hash_key: ["stuff", "more stuff", "more stuff"]
  },
  {
    first_hash_key: {id: 1, title: "my title"},
    second_hash_key: ["stuff 3", "uniq stuff 2"]
  },
  {
    first_hash_key: {id: 2, title: "my other title"},
    second_hash_key: ["interesting stuff", "uniq stuff"]
  }
]
```

I want to combine hashes by `first_hash_key[:id]`, add each item in `hash_key_two` to an array, not overwrite them to get:

```
my_array = [
  {
    first_hash_key: {id: 1, title: "my title"},
    second_hash_key: [
      ["stuff", "more stuff", "more stuff"],
      ["stuff 3", "uniq stuff 2"]
    ]
  },
  {
    first_hash_key: {id: 2, title: "my other title"},
    second_hash_key: ["interesting stuff", "uniq stuff"]
  }
]
```

I can reduce the top level array and hash, and use `merge`, but I'm losing the individual arrays inside the hash.

I've also tried grouping by the `id` of the `first_hash_key`, and then injecting like this:

```
my_array.group_by{|h| h[:first_hash_key]}.map{|k,v| v.inject(:merge)}
```

Again, I'm losing the arrays in the `second_hash_key`. I only get the last array listed. Without `map`, I get an array of each hash in the group, but the top level isn't combined.

```
[
  {
    :first_hash_key=>{:id=>1, :title=>"my title"},
    :second_hash_key=>["stuff 3", "uniq stuff 2"]
  },
  {
    :first_hash_key=>{:id=>2, :title=>"my other title"}, 
    :second_hash_key=>["interesting stuff", "uniq stuff"]
  }
]
```

**Update**
As noted by sawa and cary, there is no sense in guessing for the second_hash_key if the data is an array or array or arrays, better to always have an array of arrays.  The desired output is:

```
 [{:first_hash_key=>{:id=>1, :title=>"my title"}, 
   :second_hash_key=>[["stuff", "more stuff", "more stuff"], 
                      ["stuff 3", "uniq stuff 2"]]
 },
 {:first_hash_key=>{:id=>2, :title=>"my other title"}, 
 :second_hash_key=>[["interesting stuff", "uniq stuff"]]
 }]
```

Comment: Where is `hash_key_two`?

Comment: Suppose `my_array[1][:first_hash_key]` equaled `{id: 1, title: "my dog"}`. How (if at all) would that change the desired result. Perhaps if two hashes have the same value of `:id` they have the same value of `:title`.

Comment: As @sawa intimated in a comment below you are making life unnecessarily difficult for yourself by not always having the value of `:second_hash_key` be an array of arrays, even when it contains just one array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it ain't pretty but here you go:

```
my_array.
  group_by { |elem| elem[:first_hash_key] }.
  transform_values { |vals| vals.map { |val| val[:second_hash_key] } }.
  reduce([]) do |memo, (key, vals)|
    memo + [{first_hash_key: key, second_hash_key: vals}]
  end
```

returns:

```
[
  {
    :first_hash_key=>{:id=>1, :title=>"my title"},
    :second_hash_key=>[
      ["stuff", "more stuff", "more stuff"],
      ["stuff 3", "uniq stuff 2"]
    ]
  }, {
    :first_hash_key=>{:id=>2, :title=>"my other title"},
    :second_hash_key=>[
      ["interesting stuff", "uniq stuff"]
    ]
  }
]
```

If you're not clear how this works you should inspect the result of each line, but to summarize

1. group by `first_hash_key`
2. call `transform_values` to get the values at `second_hash_key` corresponding to each of these `first_hash_key` values
3. At this point you have a hash mapping `first_hash_key` value to all of the corresponding values of `second_hash_key`. Now just have to `reduce` it to get the final data structure.

This pattern of group_by => transform_values => reduce is something I use all the time and is very useful. transform_values is available in rails as well as ruby 2.5 I believe.

Comment: The result of your code is more consistent and makes sense, but is different from what OP wanted. For the value of `:second_hash_key` in the hash where `[:first_hash_key][:id] == 2`, the OP did not want a nested array. What OP wanted is inconsistent and makes less sense, but is not what your code returns.

Comment: Actually - I do want a nested array, and max's code returns a nested array - I incorrectly posted my desired return.  I need to be able to iterate over the arrays from second_hash_key.  I can update the question

Answer (score 0):

```
my_array.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:first_hash_key][:id]=>g) { |_,o,n|
    o.merge(second_hash_key: [[*o[:second_hash_key]], n[:second_hash_key]]) }
end.values
  #=> [{:first_hash_key=>{:id=>1, :title=>"my title"},
  #     :second_hash_key=>[["stuff", "more stuff", "more stuff"],
  #                        ["stuff 3", "uniq stuff 2"]]},
  #    {:first_hash_key=>{:id=>2, :title=>"my other title"},
  #     :second_hash_key=>["interesting stuff", "uniq stuff"]}]
```

The receiver of [Hash#values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-values) is the hash:

```
{1=>{:first_hash_key=>{:id=>1, :title=>"my title"},
     :second_hash_key=>[["stuff", "more stuff", "more stuff"],
                        ["stuff 3", "uniq stuff 2"]]},
 2=>{:first_hash_key=>{:id=>2, :title=>"my other title"},
     :second_hash_key=>["interesting stuff", "uniq stuff"]}}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged, here the keys being `1` and `2`. That block has three block variables: `_` equals the common key<sup>1</sup>; `o` ("old") is value of the key `_` in the hash being constructed and `n` ("new") is the value of the key `_` in the hash being merged into the hash being constructed.

The expression `[*o[:second_hash_key]]` converts `o[:second_hash_key]` to an array of itself if `o[:second_hash_key]` is not an array and leaves `o[:second_hash_key]` unchanged if it is already an array. For example, `[*1] #=> [1]`, whereas `[*[1,2]] #=> [1,2]`.

The return value is problematic in that the value of `:second_hash_key` is in one case an array of arrays and in another it is simply an array. In subsequent calculations it therefore will be necessary to determine if each value is an array of arrays or just an array, and then take action accordingly. That could be done, of course, but it's messy and ugly; better to make all the values arrays of arrays. We could do that as follows.

```
my_array.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:first_hash_key][:id]=>
    g.merge(second_hash_key: [g[:second_hash_key]])) { |_,o,n|
      o.merge(second_hash_key: o[:second_hash_key] + n[:second_hash_key]) }
end.values
  #=> [{:first_hash_key=>{:id=>1, :title=>"my title"},
  #     :second_hash_key=>[["stuff", "more stuff", "more stuff"],
  #                        ["stuff 3", "uniq stuff 2"]]},
  #    {:first_hash_key=>{:id=>2, :title=>"my other title"},
  #     :second_hash_key=>[["interesting stuff", "uniq stuff"]]}]
```

<sup>1 The use of the underscore--a valid local variable--for the common key is to inform the reader that it is not used in the block calculation.</sup>

Comment: So noted.  I agree, too much work to guess at the data within second_hash_key - updated output required.  thanks!!!!